# How to alter the hash values with new values in perl?

Tags: perl, data-structures, hash

How can i reset the hash values in perl

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my %hash = qw(one 1 two 2 three 3 four 4);
my @key = keys(%hash);
my @avz = (9..12);
my %vzm;
print "Original hash and keys : ",%hash,"\n";
for(my $i = 0; $i<=scalar @avz; $i++){
    my @new = "$key[$i] $avz[$i] ";
    push(%vzm , @new);
}
print "modified hash and keys",%vzm,"\n";
```

I tried to alter the keys of original hash with another keys. How can i do it 
This program give the error is:

```
 Original hash and keys : three3one1two2four4
 Not an ARRAY reference at key.pl line 10.
```

I expect the output is

```
 Original hash and keys : three3one1two2four4
 modified hash and keys : three11one9two10four12
```

How can i do it

Comment: You try to push in a HASH, push is for ARRAYs

Comment: @sputnick What can i try for hashes?

Comment: Be sure as well to see [`perldsc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) which is the main documentation reference. Perl Maven has a [pretty good basic summary of hashes](http://perlmaven.com/perl-hashes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep the order of the keys in some array, or take it from original list

```
my @tmp = qw(one 1 two 2 three 3 four 4);
my %hash = @tmp;
# 'one', 'two', ..
my @key = @tmp[ grep !($_%2), 0 .. $#tmp ];


# ..
for my $i (0 .. $#avz) {

  $vzm{ $key[$i] } = $avz[$i];
}
```

or using hash slice as more perlish approach,

```
@vzm{ @key } = @avz;
```

Comment: i expect output is `three11one9two10four12`

Answer (score 2):

Ok, first off - you're doing something nasty in your code:

You're trying to take an ordered data structure - an array - and push it into a keyed data structure, which has no particular ordering defined.

This isn't going to work very well - it technically works, because internally perl treats arrays and hashes similarly.

But for example your first assignment - what you're *actually* getting is:

```
my %hash = (
    one   => 1,
    two   => 2,
    three => 3,
    four  => 4
);
```

You can access the keys (in no particular order) via `keys()`. And the values via `values()`. But to try and treat it like an array is undefined behaviour.

To add elements to your array:

```
$hash{'nine'} = 9;
```

To delete elements from your array:

```
delete ( $hash{'one'} );
```

You can iterate on `keys` or `values` - and combined with `sort` even do them in some sort of order. (Just bear in mind for sorting alphanumeric numbers you'll have a custom sort job).

```
 foreach my $key ( sort keys %hash ) { 
    print "$key => $hash{$key}\n";
 }
```

(Note - this is sorting by alphanumeric string, so gives:

```
four => 4
one => 1
three => 3
two => 2
```

If you want to sort by value:

```
 foreach my $key ( sort { $hash{$a} <=> $hash{$b} } keys %hash ) { 
    print "$key => $hash{$key}\n";
 }
```

And so you'll get:

```
one => 1
two => 2
three => 3
four => 4
```

So the real question remains - what are you actually trying to accomplish? The *point* of a hash is to give you an unordered mini-database of key-value pairs. Treating one like an array doesn't make an awful lot of sense. Either you're iterating hash elements in arbitrary order, or you're applying a specific sort to it - but one where you're relying on getting elements in a particular order is a bad plan - it may work, but it's not *guaranteed* to work, and that makes for bad code.

Comment: ++ Someone once told me when you are thinking of data and accessing it in a way that assumes some elements of the dataset come **before or after** some others - you are thinking of arrays. When you are thinking of data and accessing it by reference to a **naming scheme** for parts of the dataset - you are thinking of hashes. It seems obvious but the key (no pun intended) is to think carefully about how the data and its structure effect the way you use it.

Comment: It's quite true. Arrays and hashes may seem similar, and have similar structures but they're all about the data model. I remain of the opinion that hashes are one of Perl's biggest 'selling points' - lots of languages can do arrays

Answer (score 1):

To create a hash element, you use assignment to `$var{$key}`.

```
for (my $i = 0; $i < scalar @avz; $i++) {
    $vzm{$key[$i]} = $avz[$i];
}
```

Note also that the loop condition should be `<`, not `<=`. List/array indexes end at `scalar @avz - 1`.

Comment: it gives three9one10two11four12

Comment: The order of keys in a hash is arbitrary. Take a look at the order in the `Original hash and keys`.

Comment: i expect output is `three11one9two10four12`

Comment: Why do you expect that? The keys are in the same order as the original hash, the values are in the order from the `@avz` list.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what you want (replace the values for keys in the hash in the order they originally were added) without keeping track of that order separately, since the hash doesn't have any particular order.  In other words, this:

```
my @key = keys(%hash);
```

needs to be this:

```
my @key = ( 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four' );
```

Once you have that, you can just assign the values all at once with a hash slice:

```
my %vzm;
@vzm{@key} = @avz;
```